# How do I run a copied project in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, npm-install

https://github.com/gleitz/mahjong

I want to run this app on my windows,
the directions say:
-Install dependencies with npm update
-Start the application with node app.js

it's sound easy so I try myself.

1.Fist of all , I install node.js on it's official website (https://nodejs.org/en/)
I　download the 8.9.3 version.

after installing node.js
2.open the command line and go to the project path.

3.then I input the command npm update.
it works,and the node_modules folder is created.But there are some warn message
[image: warn message]

4.finally input the command node app.js... it's not work with many error message

following is wrong message

[image: error message 1]
[image: error message 2]

I wonder know how should I do.Is any thing I didn't installed?

Please help me.I really want to research this mahjong project.

Comment: It looks like you need an environment file (.env). Maybe that file contains passwords, config parameters, database conn chain, or stuff like that... You may need read the code to see what you need to include in that file

Comment: The .env file is supposed to contain your local settings like database username and password. Unfortunately it looks like the project isn't as easy to set up as the documentation claims – you need to run at least a MongoDB instance, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Before running `npm update` in the directory where you have your project, you should run `npm install` first to install all the required dependencies needed for the project to run.

So I advice to delete the node_modules directory that was created after you ran `npm update`, after which you can then run `npm install`. This should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Update: If you just want to try it online and not run it locally they've hosted a version on the web: http://gleitzman.com/apps/mahjong.

---

**It's not your fault.**

What you did was correct, but the project documentation needs to be updated. It's not a turn-key solution and you'll need to figure a few things out to get it working.

The error message is says it wants a mongo db instance, but you don't have one running. Try the [mongodb home page](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center) or google for instructions. If you have docker it is pretty easy: `docker run -it -p 27017:27017 mongo`.

Even after spinning up mongodb I wasn't able to get the app to work locally. You could try contacting the repo maintainer for assistance. They may be happy to help given you've shown interest in their project.

Good Luck!